# PhpStorm - all files have blue font (no color coding for methods/properties)

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-valet

I created a new project using Laravel's command `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

When I open it in PhpStorm, all the files look like this:

[image: blue colored font]

I haven't done anything at all but any file I open has the same color text and when I type anything I get no text suggestions.

Has anyone had this issue before?

P.S. Valet works and I can run the project in localhost.

Comment: Go to Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > PHP and apply the scheme you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess that somehow your files aren't being associated with PHP. You can reset this in settings by making sure that files ending in `.php` are recognized by PHPStorm as PHP files:

[image: PHPStorm File Types interface]

Image of PHPStorm 2018.1

In settings, go to *Editor -> File Types -> PHP* and make sure that `*.php` (or whatever your exotic PHP extension is) is present. Hit Apply.

Comment: yea that's what it was, eventually PhPStorm pointed that out to me